# Server not available 503 - WebClient.DownloadData

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to scrap a site using this code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.170 Safari/537.36");
byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(URL);
```

but the problem is that it returns for some sites, i.e. www.amazon.ca an error 
"Server not available 503" and when i commented this line

```
 client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.170 Safari/537.36");
```

it downloaded this page [result without a header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Soe.png).

after that i uncommented the line again and it downloaded the site without having any exception!
Any explanation why this happened?

Comment: So, what is your question? Why not every site on internet behaves the same?

Comment: same site returned the exception for the first time and then it worked, so i'm wondering why this happened.

Comment: Sounds like they have at least somewhat effective means to prevent you from scraping their site.